# Need tornado to resolve parameters

Tags: get, tornado

My case is maybe silly and simple..but help me please :) 
I'm sending a parameter (single character) via android application using the GET request to a tornado server.. all what i need is tornado to resolve the parameter sent to it in order to compare it with a value..
i saw some documentation with examples using such as :

```
    def get(self):
     cmd = self.get_arguements(command,TRUE)
     if self.get_arguements == "a" :
     ...do something
```

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's modify the example code from [tornadoweb](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

```
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.web

    class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            print("Hello!")  # Just so you see that the right handler is invoked
            # Lets get what's in the ?command=...
            cmd = self.get_argument("command", None)
            if cmd == 'd':
                print("You passed in the 'd' command")
            elif cmd == 'r':
                print("We got the r command!")
            else:
                print("Command unknown :(")

    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application.listen(80)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This assumes the request looks something like this:

```
GET /?command=d
```

Comment: thanks but where should i define the name of the parameter? in android or in tornado?
in android im sending to the url ("192.168.1.111/?command="+cmd) is my  syntax right? :/

Comment: Yes, that looks good. So what ever you set `cmd` to in Android it will be stored in the `cmd` var in your server. You could insert a print directly after the `def self):` line so you're sure the correct handler is invoked.

Comment: thanks alot! this actually worked just fine on the server side, but the android app crashes right after i get the message from the server :D

Comment: Great, well done! Android isn't my cup of tea, but I'm sure you'll find someone else to help you out!